# Edit mysql db field and insert multible many numbers

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have a db field called Product id and contain a single id ex 300.

I need to insert (manuel in phpmyadmin) multible id´s ex 300,301,302

How do i do that?

I have tried with , seperatet but get a error.

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I get "0 rows affected.
Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column 'product_id' at row 1"  when i enter 3527,3528